# Adding percentage to plotly bar

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data, https://www.kaggle.com/ahsen1330/us-police-shootings and am using plotly bar to visualize the data this is my code.

```
trace1= go.Bar(x=df['race'].value_counts().index, y=df['race'].value_counts())

trace2= go.Bar(x = df['threat_level'].value_counts().index, y=df['threat_level'].value_counts())

trace3= go.Bar(x=df['flee'].value_counts().index, y=df['flee'].value_counts())

trace4= go.Bar(x=df['arms_category'].value_counts().index, y=df['arms_category'].value_counts(), )

trace5 = go.Bar(x=df['year'].value_counts().index, y=df['year'].value_counts())

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "bar"},{"type": "bar"}],
                                           [{"type": "bar"},{"type": "bar"}],
                                          [{"type": "bar"},None]],
                   subplot_titles=('Race Distribution','Threat Level Count In US Shooting','Flee In US Shooting',
                                  'Arms Category Used In US Shooting','Which Year Most Shooting occured'))

fig.append_trace(trace1,1,1)
fig.append_trace(trace2,1,2)
fig.append_trace(trace3,2,1)
fig.append_trace(trace4,2,2)
fig.append_trace(trace5,3,1)

fig['layout'].update(title='US Police Shooting Univariate Analysis',
                    height=1100, width=900,)
fig.update_traces(marker_color=['papayawhip','peachpuff','peru','pink','plum','powderblue','purple'])

fig.show()
```

I want to add percentage at the top of graph but don't know how to do it. I have tried searching online for solution but can't seem to find solution for this.
Really appreciate if someone can guide me.

Comment: The answer has already been accepted, but I wrote the code for my own learning. I was able to add percentages, but I ran into a strange phenomenon where the first five percentages in the graph were not displayed. Did it work for you?

Comment: This is the code that i wrote and it works for me                                                     
trace1= go.Bar(x=df['race'].value_counts().index, y=df['race'].value_counts(), text=((df['race'].value_counts()/len(df['race)*100)                                                                                                                                                             fig.update_traces(,textposition='outside',texttemplate='%{text:.4s}')                                       Hope this helps you.

Comment: `df['race'].value_counts().sum()` or `sum(df['race'].value_counts())`Isn't this correct?

Comment: Since the amount of code became too much, we created a data frame for annotations to handle it.

Comment: I wrote the code using df['race'].value_counts() i don't know if df['race'].value_counts().sum() works or not.

Comment: I meant `len(df['race]` in the comment, so it must be a mistake for `sum()`. I encourage self-answering if you get the intended result, for the benefit of SO users.

Comment: len(df['race'])  and   df['race'].value_counts().sum()  gives the same result so I guess you can use either one. Sorry  if my explanation doesn't make any sense, I'm a beginner myself.

Comment: I was mistaken. I thought it was a numerical sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
fig = go.Bar(text='calc')
```

in your bar part.

e.g. here:

```
go.Bar(x=df['year'].value_counts().index, y=df['year'].value_counts())
```

Where 'calc' are the calculated percentages you have to add to your data set as columns as the police shooting data set has no % as columns. We do not know which percentages you want so you have to calculate them by yourself.

In addition add the position for the text outside of the bars:

```
fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
```